# Pandas dataframe - comparison of the two nearest rows with the condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have such a problem:

What I already have - In the `Equal` column the values are `True` or `False` depending on the values in `col_1` and `col_3` - if these values are the same, then in the `Equal` column it is `True`, if the others are `False`

If there is `False` then I have to check it - if there is a different value in `col_1` than `in col_3` then this is an improvement of `False` and it should stay that way, but if there is `False` and 0 in `col_1` then it should be compared with the two closest rows.

For example:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| col_1 | group | col_3 | Equal |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 14    | 7     | 15    | True  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 140   | 6     | 120   | False |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 0     | 5     | 0     | True  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 100   | 4     | 100   | True  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 0     | 3     | 300   | False |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 300   | 2     | 300   | True  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 20    | 1     | 20    | True  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

here the value of `col_1` is 0 where Equal is `False` - in this case when there is 0 in `col_1`, value from `col_3` should be compared with `col_3` on the two nearest rows where it is `True`
In this case in the rows where there is group 2 - here the same value of `col_3` and it is True. In this case the line where False is present should be deleted and the whole should look like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| col_1 | group | col_3 | Equal |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 14    | 7     | 15    | True  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 140   | 6     | 120   | False |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 0     | 5     | 0     | True  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 100   | 4     | 100   | True  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 300   | 2     | 300   | True  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 20    | 1     | 20    | True  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Only if there are `False` in the rows and the value in `col_1` is 0 - then the values between `col_3` and the two nearest rows that return `True` should be compared - if the values in `col_3` between these rows are the same, then the whole row where `False` occurred should be deleted

```
+---------+-------+-------+---------+
| 140     | 6     | 120     | False | <- col_1 is not 0 - should not be deleted
+---------+-------+-------+---------+
| 100     | 4     | 100     | True  |
+---------+-------+-------+---------+
| *0*     | 3     | *300*   | False | <- Should be deleted - col_1 = 0 and nearest True row return same col_3 value
+---------+-------+-------+---------+
| *300*   | 2     | *300*   | True  | <- Nearest row returns True and col_3 value is same
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I was thinking about a solution where I would take group values from these columns where `False` is and compare them with values where group values are +1 and -1, but I don't know how to do that - I was trying to take these values for individual rows, store them in lists, then compare and finally delete them, but this way I am circumventing the possibilities of df.

Comment: Which one of the nearest column of `True` do you want to replace with? The previous occurrance or the next one?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan I mean to compare the two nearest rows where `False` occurs. In this line where there are values: `0|3|300|False` below is the line with values: `300| 2|300|True` - `col_3` is the same for these two rowss so the line where False is to be deleted. For the second row where `False` exist - `|140|6|120|False` - here `col_1` is not equal to 0 so it should not be checked and this `False` there is correct

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan I have updated the first entry for a more detailed description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I wrote and is based on index values:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    |   col_1 |   col_2 |   col_3 | Equal   |
|----+---------+---------+---------+---------|
|  0 |       1 |       3 |       1 | True    |
|  1 |       0 |       2 |       3 | False   | <-- Should be deleted
|  2 |       2 |       1 |       3 | True    |
|  3 |       3 |       5 |       3 | False   |
|  4 |       0 |       5 |       4 | False   | <-- Should be deleted
|  5 |       3 |       5 |       4 | True    |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    |   col_1 |   col_2 |   col_3 | Equal   |
|----+---------+---------+---------+---------|
|  0 |       1 |       3 |       1 | True    |
|  2 |       2 |       1 |       3 | True    |
|  3 |       3 |       5 |       3 | False   |
|  5 |       3 |       5 |       4 | True    |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

```
lst = [[1,3,1,True],[0,2,3,False],[2,1,3,True],[3,5,3,False],[0,5,4,False],[3,5,4,True]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df.columns = ['col_1','col_2','col_3','Equal']

df1 = df[(df['Equal'] == False) & (df['col_1'] == 0)]
index = df1.index.tolist()

list=[]
for x in range(len(index)):
    index_max = df.index.max()
    df1 = df[(df['Equal'] == False) & (df['col_1'] == 0)]
    index = df1.index.tolist()
    index_prev = index[x] - 1
    
    if index[x] != index_max:
       index_next = index[x] + 1
    else:
        index_next = index_prev

    index = index[x]
    if df.iloc[index_prev][3] != False or df.iloc[index_next][3] != False:
        if (df.iloc[index][2] == df.iloc[index_next][2] or df.iloc[index][2] == df.iloc[index_prev][2]):
            list.append(df.index[index])
df.drop(index=list, inplace = True)
```

I've been checking and it works as well, but it's not the solution I've been expecting - I think there's a little bit of "unnecessary" code there, which can be easily replaced by a pandas alone